# How to retrieve name of user in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app (Xcode, swift) that has a profile page for each user and I want their name to appear on that page.

I have been able to get their email address through:

```
let email : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!
```

How would I gather the users name? I have the users UID as well.

I am using firebase by the way

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Google or Facebook to log in with firebase, You need to manually create the profile for each user. See [Update a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a social provider to sign in, you can get the display name from that provider through Firebase with:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
```

If you're signing in with another provider, the display name won't automatically be set, and you will (as Abdullah answered) have to create your own registration system where the user enters their name - and you then store it in the `displayName` property of Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you requested, you either have to use a social auth provider (such as Google or Facebook) or change it yourself from the client, as the other answers suggest.

First of all, you would have to create a `changeRequest`, using the following code

```swift
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
```

Once the change request is created, you can change whatever basic information you need to (either the photo URL or the display name) with the following code:

```swift
changeRequest?.displayName = "Lorem ipsum"
changeRequest?.photoURL = "https://your_link/path_to_image.png"
```

Finally, you must send the change request to Firebase, which will handle it and possibly return an error for you to handle.

```swift
changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        // You can handle the given error here
        return
    }
}
```

As others have already pointed out, you can find this and more information on the official [on the official Firebase docs website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).